# Array to string conversion, from dropdown form

Tags: php, codeigniter, parameters, dropdown

I'm relatively new to PHP. I got the following error, and even though I saw many duplicate questions with answers related to the function parameters, I couldn't figure out how to solve this one:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Array to string conversion
>
> Filename: helpers/form_helper.php
>
> Line Number: 304

This is the code, and you can see the line number 304 next to the comment:

```
if ( ! function_exists('form_dropdown'))
{
    function form_dropdown($name = '', $options = array(), $selected = array(), $extra = '')
    {
        if ( ! is_array($selected))
        {
            $selected = array($selected);
        }

        if (count($selected) === 0)
        {
            if (isset($_POST[$name]))
            {
                $selected = array($_POST[$name]);
            }
        }

        if ($extra != '') $extra = ' '.$extra;  //Line Number: 304

        $multiple = (count($selected) > 1 && strpos($extra, 'multiple') === FALSE) ? ' multiple="multiple"' : '';

        $form = '<select name="'.$name.'"'.$extra.$multiple.">\n";

        foreach ($options as $key => $val)
        {
            $key = (string) $key;

            if (is_array($val))
            {
                $form .= '<optgroup label="'.$key.'">'."\n";

                foreach ($val as $optgroup_key => $optgroup_val)
                {
                    $sel = (in_array($optgroup_key, $selected)) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';

                    $form .= '<option value="'.$optgroup_key.'"'.$sel.'>'.(string) $optgroup_val."</option>\n";
                }

                $form .= '</optgroup>'."\n";
            }
            else
            {
                $sel = (in_array($key, $selected)) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';

                $form .= '<option value="'.$key.'"'.$sel.'>'.(string) $val."</option>\n";
            }
        }

        $form .= '</select>';

        return $form;
    }
}
```

This is a code that provides some values:

```
    $config['field']['activation_method'] = array('type'=>'dropdown','params'=>array('options'=>array('none'=>$this->lang->line('preference_field_activation_method_none'),'email'=>$this->lang->line('preference_field_activation_method_email'),'admin'=>$this->lang->line('preference_field_activation_method_admin'))));
```

Then the reference to that code calling the form_dropdown function is here:

```
function _field_dropdown($key)
{
    $options = $this->field[$key]['params']['options'];
    unset($this->field[$key]['params']['options']);
    return form_dropdown($key,$options,$this->CI->validation->{$key},$this->field[$key]['params']);
}
```

Comment: If that error is occurring where you are indicating, then that would suggest that $extra is an array instead of a string. Can you show the surrounding code where you are calling this?

Comment: I don't see any reference to that code calling the form_dropdown function. So that does not help. There must be a bit more going on here that you need to show.

Comment: I know that type hinting is unable to be used for a string, but you should check if the value is a string by using PHP's built in function `is_string($var)` the built in function will return a boolean, so maybe you could put that in an if statement. If you really need to use type hinting, then i suggest that you take a look at the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php  Also, If you could provide a `var_dump()` of the values that you are passing, that would be good to. This would allow us to identify the problem at hand.

Comment: Your error says its only a notice, which usually means the code will run, but you might have problems. For example doing an array to String conversion like that is not the proper way to do the conversion. So could you tell us what problems you are running into.

Comment: @georgiaboy82 it is always recommended that you fix all errors before attempting to go into production. It is just good practice in my opinion.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I've updated the question once again, with the reference to that code calling the form_dropdown function.

Comment: It would appear that whoever wrote this code, got a little bit too clever, too quickly. It seems overly complicated for simply creating a dropdown with selections. I'd suggest going back to basics and work from there and get brushed up on some debug skills.

Comment: I honestly don't know how it works, but I deleted the last parameter from the reference that calls the form_dropdown function and now it seems to work well.

`return form_dropdown($key,$options,$this->CI->validation->{$key});`

Comment: Your 4th Parameter was an array and not a string as expected. So removing it would fix it as such and obviously wasn't required. Performing a var_dump() on it would reveal it's structure and content.